# ToolbarManager help Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, toolbar

I can't figure out what toolbar part this is called or how to get rid of it:

[image]

It is rather unsightly and I know it can be removed. Can someone please shed some light on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

it is called overflow. 
can you try to read this article : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/common-interface-controls/toolbar-control/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, it seems like your link is broken. I'll look into it though. Thanks again!